# Python: Compare lists, perform operation, create new list

Tags: python, list

I am currently studying python and have run into a problem I can't seem to find a solution for. I hope some of you may help me.

The problem is as follows:

I have three lists, each with 3000 elements. The first five elements of each list are as follows:

`A = [100, 101, 100, 99, 100...]
B = [100, 102, 101, 98, 101...]
C = [100, 103, 100, 99, 100...]`

I need to create a new list called D with the following rules:

For each *element* of list D, I need Python to first choose between lists A, B and C for the one with the lowest value for that same *index*. That is, to determine what will be the 0eth element of the list D, Python first needs to choose between lists A, B and C for the one with the smallest element for that index. Whenever there are more that one list with the same smallest value for the index in question, Python needs to choose randomly between those lists.

In the case of the 0eth element of List D, because all three reference lists have the same 0eth element (namely 100), Python needs to randomly pick between the three.

Let's say Python randomly picks list B. Then, to determine the 0eth element of list D, python will divide the last element of list B by its 0eth element. Lets say the last element of list B was 130. In this case, the 0eth element of list D will be 1.3.

Continuing, for list D's index=1 element, Python will immediately choose list A, because it has the lowest index=1 element. Then, python will divide the last element of list A by the list A's index=1 element. Let's say it was 145. In this case, list D's index=1 element will be 145 / 101 = 1.4356

In the end, list D will also have 3000 elements.

Does anyone know how to code to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Next time, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of any attempts you've made to try to solve your problem. That aside, consider using python's inbuilt [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function

Answer (score 0):

I think the downvotes are justified because you did not provide any code at all to show us what you tried so far, so that we know where you are stuck with your code. Also i think the way you wrote the requirements is a bit confusing (0eth probably means nth sometimes?). Anyways, this is not hard to do - All you need is `zip`, `min`, a list comprehension and `random.choice` and you can work with `n` lists:

```
from random import choice

a = [100, 101, 100, 99, 100, 110]
b = [100, 102, 101, 98, 101, 130]
c = [100, 103, 100, 99, 100, 120]

# In order to work properly with indexes 
# we should rely on a list of lists
lists = [a, b, c]
# Collect the last value of each sublist in lists
last_values = [sublist[-1] for sublist in lists]
# Your d list
result = []

# zip combines each element from each given list on the same index
# splat the sublists with * (keeps the proper order of sublists)
for zipped in zip(*lists):
  # min selects the lowest value in the zipped values
  lowest = min(zipped)
  # find all occurences of the lowest value within zipped values
  indexes = [i for i, v in enumerate(zipped) if v == lowest]
  # pick a random index (len(indexes) doesn't matter)
  random_index = choice(indexes)
  # Divide the last value in the picked list with the lowest value
  value = last_values[random_index] / lowest
  # And add to result
  result.append(value)

print(result)
```